# NSTimer timer reset

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, cocoa, timer, nstimer

I'm developing an app that which has a timer that countdowns to a specific date and time of an event:

```
   destinationDate = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSince1970:1403938831];
timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1.0 target:self selector:@selector(updateLabel) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
```

The command I'm trying to implement is something like: when it reaches 0, it begins a new countdown to a new future event.

I'm very new to objective C and was wondering how I go abut doing this.

Thanks!

Comment: are you looking for [timer invalidate]; ?

Comment: Not really, I have a set of dates for future events. The countdown timer counts down to the closest date, but once it reaches that date, I need the timer to countdown to the next date (process repeated for the other dates) thanks for your help

Comment: Strikes me that when you reach your `destinationDate`, you could, as pawan suggested, simply `invalidate` the existing timer, adjust your `destinationDate` variable to the next event (if any), and then schedule a new timer, much like you've scheduled the first one above. I'm unclear as to what the question is.

Comment: yes, that's what I'm after. My question is how do I get this to happen, I'm quite new coding and I'm having problems implementing the timer

Answer (score 0):

I will only briefly line out the main aspects:
I assume you have an ordered `NSArray` of `NSDates` and a property for a `NSTimer`.

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSArray *dates;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSTimer *timer;
```

Now you need a method, which returns the first date, which hasn't already passed.

```
-(NSDate *)giveMeADate
{
    for(NSDate *date in self.dates){
        if([date laterDate:[NSDate date]] === date){
            return date;
        }
    }
    return nil;
}
```

And a method, which sets the timer:

```
-(void)setTimer
{
    self.timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1.0 target:self selector:@selector(updateLabel) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
}
```

And finally update the `UILabel`

```
-(void)updateLabel
{
    NSDate *futureDate = [self giveMeADate];
    NSdate *now = [NSDate date];

    NSTimeInterval secondsBetween = [futureDate timeIntervalSinceDate:now];

    self.label.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i seconds to go", (int)secondsBetween];
}
```

So the point is: Your timer does not count to an event, your timer ticks and ticks and your application does the logic.